# How to reload already loaded uiwebview with new HTML string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, refresh, reload

I have implemented `UIWebView` in my project to show some HTML data. The problem is I have loaded the **webview** with some HTML string by using the method

```
[myWebView loadHTMLString:Data baseURL:nil];
```

Now I want to add action of button such that when user click on the button the new data is loaded in the **webview**. such that

```
-(void)clicked{
[myWebView loadHTMLString:newData baseURL:nil];
}
```

I tried by applying the same as above but no affect was there. I also tried [myWebView reload], but nothing happened.

Plz tell me the appropriate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRy with, First call stopLoading then  reload on your `UIWebView` instance.

```
[myWebView  stopLoading ];
[myWebView  reload];
```

Comment: Thanks for it. Finally I did it by my hit and trial method. I put all the WebView loading method in viewDidLoad and it works as I required.

Answer (score 0):

`loadHTMLString:baseURL:` is the correct method.

But still some things might be wrong, such as the data you are trying to send to the webview. Did you try logging your newData object to see what is being send to the webView object?

Is your newData string loaded from a resource file? If so, you could try loading you html data from the resources with something like the code bellow

```
NSString *html = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFileName" ofType:@"html"]];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after trying accepted answer I have not got my issue solved. 
So, after spending some time I found below logic which works for me: 
**Objective-c**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                [myWebView  reload];
            })
```

**Swift**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { 
                    myWebView.reload()
                })
```